# Is it possible to create a POSTGRESQL schema in CodeIgniter Migrations

Tags: php, database, postgresql, codeigniter, migration

I am moving a project to CodeIgniter. The project uses a **Postgres** database to store data. I want to create a **CodeIgniter** migration to create the database for this project. I have looked through the CodeIgniter docs but I can't seem to find a way to create **schemas** in my database. I want to know if it is possible to create the schemas in my migrations because the whole project depends on the schemas for all DB queries. It's a large project so changing each query will be impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a schema by using a DB query in the migrations up function by using this

```
$query = $this->db->query('CREATE SCHEMA your-schema-name');
if(!$query){
    echo 'Failed to create SCHEMA';
    exit;
}
```